# How can I create api forgot password and change password in laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-api

**How can I create API for forgot password and change password in laravel use passport?**

**route : **

[image]

**Image of postman : **
[image]

** Parameter pass in api: **
[image]

Comment: Hope this link will help you and others  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046941/9077019

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**api.php**

```
Route::post('forgot-password', 'Api\AuthController@forgot_password');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
 Route::post('change-password', 'Api\AuthController@change_password');
});
```

**forgot password api**

```
public function forgot_password(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $rules = array(
        'email' => "required|email",
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $validator->errors()->first(), "data" => array());
    } else {
        try {
            $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
                $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
            });
            switch ($response) {
                case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                    return \Response::json(array("status" => 200, "message" => trans($response), "data" => array()));
                case Password::INVALID_USER:
                    return \Response::json(array("status" => 400, "message" => trans($response), "data" => array()));
            }
        } catch (\Swift_TransportException $ex) {
            $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $ex->getMessage(), "data" => []);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $ex->getMessage(), "data" => []);
        }
    }
    return \Response::json($arr);
}
```

**change password api**

```
public function change_password(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $userid = Auth::guard('api')->user()->id;
    $rules = array(
        'old_password' => 'required',
        'new_password' => 'required|min:6',
        'confirm_password' => 'required|same:new_password',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $validator->errors()->first(), "data" => array());
    } else {
        try {
            if ((Hash::check(request('old_password'), Auth::user()->password)) == false) {
                $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => "Check your old password.", "data" => array());
            } else if ((Hash::check(request('new_password'), Auth::user()->password)) == true) {
                $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => "Please enter a password which is not similar then current password.", "data" => array());
            } else {
                User::where('id', $userid)->update(['password' => Hash::make($input['new_password'])]);
                $arr = array("status" => 200, "message" => "Password updated successfully.", "data" => array());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            if (isset($ex->errorInfo[2])) {
                $msg = $ex->errorInfo[2];
            } else {
                $msg = $ex->getMessage();
            }
            $arr = array("status" => 400, "message" => $msg, "data" => array());
        }
    }
    return \Response::json($arr);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202709/discussion-on-answer-by-vikas-katariya-how-can-i-create-api-forgot-password-and).

Comment: Please use the chat link above.

Comment: hello @SamuelLiew

Comment: To respect URI best practices in the REST API, use a hyphen instead of an underscore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64046941/9077019

Comment: Getting an error in Forget password api `$response =Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {$message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());});`