# Laravel forgot and reset password API with jwt authentication

Tags: laravel, flutter, jwt, forgot-password, laravel-authentication

please am trying to create a forgot password and reset password API in Laravel using JWT [image]but it gave me this error ' "email": "passwords.throttled"',
I want it to send a password reset link to the email provided but it gives me that error.
or if anyone has any idea of how I will go about it
please can anyone help

this is my code

```
 public function forgotPassword(Request $request){
    // $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);
    
    $email = $request->only('email');
    $rules = ['email'=>'required:users,email'];
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
     if ($validator->fails()) {
        // handler errors
        $erros = $validator->errors();
        // echo $erros;
        return $erros;
     }else{
         $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
         try { 
             // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
             if (! $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)) { 
                 return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
             } 
         } catch (JWTException $e) { 
             // something went wrong 
             return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500); 
         } 
         // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT 
    //  return response()->json(compact('token')); 

        $status = Password::sendResetLink($email);
    
        return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? response()->json(['status' => $status])
                : response()->json(['email' => $status]);

     }

}
public function resetPassword(Request $request)
 {   
    // $this->validate($request, [
    //         'token' => 'required',
    //         'email' => 'required|email',
    //         'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    // ]); 
    $rules = ['email'=>'required:users,email','password' => 'required|confirmed',
                'token'=>'required  '];
     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

     if ($validator->fails()) {
        // handler errors
        $erros = $validator->errors();
        // echo $erros;
        return $erros;
     }else{
        $credentials = $request->only(
                'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );  
        // $response = $request->password->reset($credentials, function($user, $password) {
        //         $user->password = bcrypt($password);
        //         $user->save();
        //         $this->auth->login($user);
        // }); 
        // return json_encode($response);
        

     }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58947560/how-can-i-create-api-forgot-password-and-change-password-in-laravel